# How to automatic simulate failure in Azure VM

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm working on Dynamic 365 project where we have environments (Azure VM's machine (AOS, BI) ).Now for testing our monthly API release we have to test our environments(Resume, rollback senarios) for that I have to manually simulate the VM failure via adding Throw "Error" keyword in any of the desync or other file ones files generate in respective folder then ones VM failed then I go to VM and remove the Throw keyword and perform Resume/rollback operation.

Now I'm planning to automate this process via yml pipeline where my pipeline task will make failure instead of myself manually doing.

One way I can think I can write a Powershell script and make VM failure though I want to make it failure then perform Resume and Rollback operation.

Can anyone help me with the best and easy approach to achieve this..? May be without modifying file or something else.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe pester testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Powershell to do this by using Azure VM [run command functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command).

By this functionality, you can run your Powershell script remotely instead of RDP to your VM and run it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your response using Run command I can stop and start VM though I want to simulate failure while Deploy Lifecycle Services (LCS) Asset Deployment to sandbox environment here the example link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-tools/pipeline-deploy-asset#add-the-task-to-a-pipeline